# Silver Searcher: how to return filename without path

Tags: ag

I am using Silver Searcher to find information in my Calibre library which, by default uses long directory and filenames that are a bit redundant. Example search:

```
chris@ODYSSEUS:~/db/ebooks/paper-art$ ag --markdown angel

Christophe Boudias (Editor)/Origami Bogota 2014 (Paginas de Origami) (2)/Origami Bogota 2014    (Paginas de Origami) - Christophe Boudias (Editor).md
8:* [16] Angel (???)
9:* [22] Christmas Angel (Uniya Filonova)

Juan Fernando Aguilera (Editor)/Origami Bogota 2013 (Paginas de Origami) (1)/Origami Bogota 2013 (Paginas de Origami) - Juan Fernando Aguilera (Editor).md
29:* [96] Inspired Origami Angel (K. Dianne Stephens)
31:* [100] Angel for Eric Joisel (Kay Kraschewski)
```

I would like to return just the filename where the whole path is shown in the example. How can I do that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The l (lowecase L) flag will return the files-with-matches instead of the lines matched.

e.g.

`$ ag -l "angel"`

you can pipe into `sed` to remove anything up to and including the final `/` which leaves the filename.

`ag -l angel | sed 's=.*/=='`

Comment: That still returns the whole path along with the filename...I'm trying to return ONLY the filename, no path!

Comment: Apologies, I missed that. Piping to SED should do it (see edit).

Comment: we could use `basename` to get that: `ag -l angel | xargs basename`

Comment: `xargs -n 1 basename` (_`-n max-args, --max-args=max-args`: Use at most max-args arguments per command line_). If not you might get `basename: extra operand` error.